# Avoid repeating data in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

so i've a gridview table binded from Microsoft SQL. Datatable (Adresses) looks like this:

```
adress_id
user_id
street
town
zip-code
```

User_id in "AddNew" RowCommand is selected via dropdownlist (from another table "users") but the problem is that i don't know how to prevent repeating of this user_id in my table. I just want to check if "x" user_id is already in table and if it exists i want to display a message "User already exists" otherwise add it.

My OnRowCommand code:

```
protected void GvAdress_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
            {

                ObAdress obdod = new ObAdress();
                string idp = (GvAdress.FooterRow.FindControl("ddFooter") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
                obdod.userid = Convert.ToInt32(idp);
                obdod.street = (GvAdress.FooterRow.FindControl("txtstreetFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim();                
                obdod.town = (GvAdress.FooterRow.FindControl("txttownFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                obdod.zip = (GvAdress.FooterRow.FindControl("txtzipFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                obdod.Add();
                PopulateGridView();
                lblSukces.Text = "added";
                lblError.Text = "";

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblSukces.Text = "";
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

If some1 was wondering ObAdress is my objector that creates query, and obdod defines values.

Comment: In AddNew_RowCommand you need to place this check- if(!dataTable.Rows["user_id").ToList().Contains(user_id)) { //Your row add logic here}

Comment: Check for the ID before insert ex: if not exists (select 1 from tableName where user_ID=give_ID) if true then do an insert else do what is needed. And for further information try to do the kind of operation in a stored procedures instead of writing an ad-hoc query.

Comment: show us some code that you did you so far so we can help you?

Comment: I added some code in my main post. @ershoaib

Comment: nevermind i did it with sql query with NOT IN